# Double arc shape with CSS jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, svg, css-shapes

How can I create an arc shape like this:

[image: shape]

With CSS or jquery or javascript

Comment: This is not possible with CSS alone. Look into using the HTML5 `canvas` element: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Drawing_Graphics_with_Canvas , in combination with Javascript.

Comment: I*m already using canvas to create a background, but i need 8 of these shapes, with custom content, and they all need to rotate. So i really thought it would be better with CSS or javascript.

Comment: You might also look at SVG.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't even need CSS/JS to draw this. Just use an `<svg>` element.

```html
<svg width="270" height="120">
    <path
       d="M 49.155517,102.32765 C 127.54837,40.541934 209.51266,103.2205 209.51266,103.2205 l 0,0 C 259.33409,50.363364 259.15552,50.363364 259.15552,50.363364 126.68749,-56.114356 2.1861831,50.204194 2.1861831,50.204194 z"
       stroke-width="3"
       stroke="#A5423A"
       fill="none"
    />
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks dude, did you make this yourself, or is there some sort of gererator?

Comment: I used a program called [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/en/) to draw it and then saved the file as an SVG. Then I opened the file in Notepad++ to get the `<path>` tag info.

Comment: Ok ill try that, since i didnt use the real shape

Comment: It would be better if this produced `A` curves instead of using `C` beziers.

Answer (score 1):

You could use SVG for this. There is an [arc path command](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html#PathDataEllipticalArcCommands) which you could use.

As your comment states, you want to place content inside the arc and you want them to rotate.

Content like text or image could be placed inside the svg. 
Rotation can be achieved with `transform=rotate(..)`.

If you want to do more animations with SVG you could have a look at [D3.js](http://d3js.org/). If you just want to create some arcs, you possibly can do the math on your own for computing the SVG path string.

Answer (score 0):

@AlliterativeAlice is correct.

But for this shape I would use two arcs instead of a lot of C paths.
I also prefer to use relative paths instead of absolute one.

So my solution used arcs and lines instead of only Bezier Curves.

```html
<svg width="300px" height="300px" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
  <path d="m 10,60 
          a 50 50 0 0 1 80,0
          l -10,10
          a 40 40 0 0 0 -60 0Z" stroke-width="1" stroke="#A5423A" fill="none" />
</svg>
```

Comment: you need to preserve the radius ratios (rx/ry) else it will create unparallel arcs

Comment: @TimKrul it will almost always create unparallel arcs since the start point and end points have a say on how the arc is displayed. Fixed so it looks as parallel as I could get it.

Comment: You need to reduce the radius of bottom arc in same proportions, and reduce it by the length of line command, or 10.  like this : if radius of top arc is 50 50, make bottom arc 40 40. https://jsfiddle.net/cLgowtry/

Comment: Here its possible to calculate the length of the line but how would I go about calculating it if it where this: http://jsfiddle.net/pw6d58et/?

Comment: to be really correct, i think it should be reduced by 10 * sqrt(2). then we will get a truly parallel arc.